# SSRS how to decrease space between textboxes

Tags: reporting-services

I have two text boxes and I want their values to be one on top of the other. With almoste no spacing. I tried to remove padding but this didn't influence much.

[image]
How it's displayed

[image]
How I want it to be displayed

Maybe the problem is that the Can grow property is turned on?

Answer (score 2):

The line space property of text-box in Reporting Services is called `LineHeight`.

Unfortunately what you want to achieve is not possible in SSRS. The LineHeight property has an effect only in HTML rendering. It is ignored for other rendering formats.

These are the options so far that I tried to set the textboxes as closely as possible.

1. 'Allow height to decrease' - To allow the text box to shrink based on its contents.

   `TextBox Properties -> General -> Sizing Options -> check 'Allow height to decrease'`
2. Set 'Padding Top = 0' and 'Bottom = 0'

   `TextBox Properties -> Alignment -> Padding Options -> Change Top = 0 and Bottom = 0`
3. Move the textboxes as closely as possible. Margin of one textbox to another is 0
4. Change your Font style and minimize your Font size (the result is more noticeable using a single textbox using break for the next line. Not very much advisable but its an option)
5. Use multiple table headers as textbox and play around with paddings. (optional)

   - Textbox on top -> Set the padding bottom = 0 and increase the padding top to push the text at the bottom.
   - Textbox below -> Set padding top = 0 and increase the padding bottom to push the text above.

---

There is another option but I haven't tried yet and don't know if possible.

- Convert the textbox value to placeholder text and set it to interpret HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You're limited to playing with the padding I'm afraid.

Items in SSRS cannot overlap, so you're limited to 2 text boxes very close to each other, with padding set to `0pt` (which is what I assume you have already tried).

In MS Word or equivalent I imagine you would want to play with the line spacing to achieve this layout, but [this is not available in SSRS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/af84ad88-f58f-44f3-b324-f2d5ca0ef9d8/line-height-or-line-spacing-in-sql-reporting-services-2008-r2-when-using-sql-server-business?forum=sqlreportingservices).

Answer (score 1):

The best result for me was to play with padding and options 'Allow height to decrease' as allready mentioned by bot. I didn't have to do anything else, not even changing Font size.

For example, I had two Textboxes, like you posted. By default all padding is set to 2pt. So what I did was to set upper Textbox to padding '**Top = 4pt**', checked option '**Allow height to decrease**', and set bottom Textbox to padding '**Top = 0pt**' with checked option '**Allow height to increase**' (I needed this because 2nd Textbox could contain data that not fits in one row).

Answer (score 0):

Should have used Rectangle box and inside rectangle box we can arrange our text boxes which will help to keep tight together to avoided the space while generating report.(if there is no space on report design)